# Jquery HTML Web app Activating Elements on load of Page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

Im making a Tomb Raider Game HTML web app For Android and iPhone and when the main page loads the tab on the bottom that says "Home" is not activated but the page is. How could I make the button Active when any of the corresponding Pages Load I have 4 Pages "Home", "Tombs", "Game Map", "Trophies"

so if i tap on "Tombs" the tombs page loads and acts like a new page but the button isnt active. I have to tap the button again to make it look activated. its annoying How do I fix this.

I am extreamly new to Javascript and JQuery Javascript so try to explain it in a noobish way

Here's what it looks like on my iPhone 
https://db.tt/zq1KyjMj

link to the app via Dropbox (don't know if it will work cuz its a private file). https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fmqbkuxqjbfbh18/TombRaiderApp.html?dl=1&token_hash=AAFU3RZVjGsKT4WLqHjWSGsP-90CfVKn5Bc3N7MgxqVo7Q

Comment: without seeing any of your code, we only only guess.  Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: link to the app via Dropbox https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fmqbkuxqjbfbh18/TombRaiderApp.html?dl=1&token_hash=AAFU3RZVjGsKT4WLqHjWSGsP-90CfVKn5Bc3N7MgxqVo7Q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any type of framework you could inspect the `window.location.pathname` or the `window.location.hash` and match that against an array or hash to figure out which button should be selected and what content to display. I wrote up a jsfiddle with jQuery as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/psyrendust/4jRQb/

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="view">
    </section>
    <nav id="footernav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tombs">Tombs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#GameMap">Game Map</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Trophies">Trophies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<script>
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var $view = $('#view');
    var $nav = $('#footernav');
    var $navli = $nav.find('li');
    var $navlinks = $nav.find('a');
    var hashtags = {};
    var content = [
        "Home Page",
        "Tombs Page",
        "Game Map Page",
        "Trophies Page"
    ];
    $navlinks.each(function (i) {
        hashtags[$(this).attr('href')] = i;
    });
    function resetNav() {
        $navli.removeClass('active');
    }
    function setActive() {
        resetNav();
        var currentHash = window.location.hash;
        var id = hashtags[currentHash] || 0;
        $($navli[id]).addClass('active');
        setContent(id);
    }
    function setContent(id) {
        $view.html(content[id]);
    }
    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        setActive();
        setContent();
    });
    setActive();
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
</script>
```